# Java Eclipse can't split using regex (Source not found)

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, split

For some reason, my program suddenly cannot split using regex. I get the error 'Source not found'.  I'm baffled.

I tried importing java.util.regex.* but that didn't change anything. My program has lots of regex splits which now no longer work.

Here is an example of one of the splits:

```
String [] test = "Happy people holding hands".split("\\s+");
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your project building against a JDK and running using a JDK? This sounds more like an issue when debugging than outright not being able to use regex.

Comment: Is this a message from Eclipse or the Java runtime? The only "Source not found" message I can think off comes from the Eclipse debugger if it can't find the source code for a class.